# How to make this picture fall below the menu bar?

Tags: css, angularjs, html, angular-material

I am using *angular material* to create a navigation bar. A chart is created using *angular-google chart*.

The navigation bar and chart looks like this;

[image]

Part of the google chart is hidden by the navigation bar.

Here is the relevant **html** code.

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" class="md-whiteframe-z3" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;position:fixed;">
    <h2>Sample navbar</h2>
</md-toolbar>

<div ng-controller="GoogleChartCtrl">
    <div google-chart chart="presence_detector_Chart" style="height:300px; width:100%;float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to make the chart fall below the navigation bar so that no part of it is hidden by the bar.

What is wrong with the html code?

Comment: Have you tried setting paddings in your 'div' ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with html. Let me check out what is paddings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the following line in to your `GoogleChartCtrl` div, like so:

```
<div ng-controller="GoogleChartCtrl" style="padding-top: 80px;">
```

This adds some space to the top of your GoogleChartCtrl div. Alternatively, you can change `padding` to `margin`.

Comment: Thanks! That is the answer. I wonder how one can make the code smart enough to automatically appear at the right position without me trying out how much padding to put at the top.

Comment: Hah! It is because of the `position: fixed` you have on the navigation bar. Fixed elements are floating, and thereby they don't collide with elements that are static, relative or so. :)

Comment: wow! Your comment is an even better answer. I changed the nav bar code to `<md-toolbar layout="row" class="md-whiteframe-z3" style="padding: 0px;margin:0px;float: left;">`

It works without the padding at the chart. Do you think there will be any disadvantage to having the navigation bar float? I wonder why the original code fixed the bar position.

Comment: Yeah well, it all depends how you want the navigation bar to act. Fixed element follows the page when it's being scrolled up and down, otherwise it just stays put.

Comment: Thanks. Learnt a lot from you!

Comment: No problem! :) You should learn CSS-basics at some point. They're quite simple, it will probably take just few days of self-learning and you can handle most of it. CSS being the styling language used to style HTML-code that is.

Answer (score 0):

The position of the navigation bar was fixed. If you made it floating, the chart would automatically be placed below the bar. The solution is to replace the fixed position with float. Here is the html code.

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" class="md-whiteframe-z3" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;float:left;">
    <h2>Sample navbar</h2>
</md-toolbar>

<div ng-controller="GoogleChartCtrl">
    <div google-chart chart="presence_detector_Chart" style="height:300px; width:100%;float: left;"></div>
</div>
```